# Gnuplot don't print title and don't print data dots

Tags: gnuplot

This source:

```
clear
reset
unset key

set terminal pngcairo

set output "speed.png"

set title "Speed w.r.t. execution time and file size"
set xlabel "file size [Byte]"
set ylabel "Time [s]"

set linetype 1 pi -1 pt 6 lc black dt solid
set linetype 2 pi -1 pt 4 lc black dt (8,6)

plot \
"speed_pc.dat" t "PC" with line, \
"speed_droid.dat" t "device" with line
```

Generates this image:

[image]

But Im't stuck because I don't understand why it doesn't prints the title of the lines and the + in data correspondence in the second line like this image (taken from the book 'Gnuplot in action 2nd):

[image]

To be clearer:
I want my second line like the 'Sparse 2'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the titles of the lines (the "key"): remove `unset key`

To plot the "+" signs: `plot ... with linespoints` instead of `plot ... with lines`.

You can get an overview of the available line and point styles by removing the complete `plot ...` command and replacing it by `test`. This will plot a test panel, and you can combine line colors, point forms, ...

I think the `dt` in your `set linetype` is new in Gnuplot 5.0, I only have 4.6 and cannot test this.